# Connect Realm with SQL Server database using mssql-data-connector

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, realm, realm-migration

We have a SQL Server database in the backend and we want to build an iOS app using Realm. While exploring possible options I found this https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/using-synced-realms/server-side-usage/data-integration/mssql-data-connector. But in this I can not find realm-mssql-adapters. Is there any way to sync data between Realm MongoDB and a SQL Server database?

We can not completely migrate from SQL Server to MongoDB and build an iOS app using realm. So we need to build a connector which sync data between SQL Server and Realm or Mongo DB.

Comment: I don't know the answer but here's a couple of things. Realm is a total product which is the datastore as well as the SDK to go with it. With MongoDB Realm, it's a NoSQL store, not SQL so the data structure concepts are radically different. Also Realm is not like CoreData with CoreData being the object graph e.g. the 'front end' which can use a variety of backends for the datastore. My question is; if you not going to use Realm as Realm, why go that route? Why not CoreData which is better suited for and SQL project?

Comment: @Jay Realm offers serverless integration with the backend and manages data sync operations very well. App that we are working on is an offline app with data sync so Realm fits perfectly for our requirement but the only issue is the backend DB is SQL server. 
The post I have shared talks about the adapter between realm and MSSQL. But is it not available temporarily or realm team is working on it or there is any other way to do it is what I am looking for.

Comment: I believe that adapter project is defunct at this point as it would take a total re-write. It's still not clear why you're trying to use Realm when you're not using the core of Realm which is its offline first database and serverless online sync solution. I am also not clear on how you can have an offline app with sync... sync to what? A local server? That again points away from Realm as that's no longer in the Realm solution. Take a look at CoreData as that's fits correctly into your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Kafka connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current) to get your SQL data into MongoDB Altas, and then sync it with your mobile devices.

Comment: This is a good solution for online apps but since the OP's question is for an *App that we are working on is an offline app with data sync*, the App is offline and local only, MongoDB Atlas isn't an option as it's an online solution.